# Can I do recursion in plain SQL? - DB2 Version 9

Tags: stored-procedures, recursion, db2

I'm creating a stored procedure to do something recursively. I want to run something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT POLICY.CONTRACT_ID
  FROM POLICY
  INNER JOIN LOAN_PART ON POLICY.LOAN_DETAIL_ID=LOAN_PART.LOAN_DETAIL_ID
    INNER JOIN APPLICATION_CONTRACTSTUB ON LOAN_PART.LOAN_PART_ID=APPLICATION_CONTRACTSTUB.LOAN_PART_ID
        INNER JOIN CONTRACTSTUB ON APPLICATION_CONTRACTSTUB.CONTRACTSTUB_ID=CONTRACTSTUB.CONTRACTSTUB_ID
 WHERE CONTRACTSTUB.REF = VARYING_REF       
   AND CONTRACTSTUB.STUB_ID = VARYING_ID;
```

It returns a VARCHAR, which I want to parse, in order to get new values for VARYING_ID and VARYING_REF, like this:

```
SET VARYING_ID = SUBSTR(RETURNED_VARCHAR, 3, 6);
SET VARYING_REF= SUBSTR(RETURNED_VARCHAR, 9, 8);
```

And recursively repeat until `RETURNED_VARCHAR` is `null` (then I will have my required VARYING_ID (I didn't design this DB)).

Now, I know I can do this with a cursor and while/for loop, or a recursive stored procedure. I just want to make sure that I am not being a little bit clumsy in so doing.

SQL has matured over the years and I remember there were some tricks in oracle for looking deep into n-level relationships, for example.

Can anyone recommend anything, or shall I get on with cursors and such things.

**EDIT -- here is some sample data:

```
CONTRACT_STUB

CONTRACTSTUB_ID        POL_REF  POL_ID
1                     qwerty    12345678
2                     asdfgh    78945612
3                     bnmxcv    45678912
4                     dfghjk    14785236
```

APPLICATION_CONTRACTSTUB
LOAN_PART_ID    CONTRACTSTUB_ID 
1           1
2           2
3           3
4           4

LOAN_PART
LOAN_DETAIL_ID   LOAN_PART_ID
1            1
2            2
3            3
4            4

POLICY
CONTRACT_ID         LOAN_DETAIL_ID
00asdfgh78945612    1
00bnmxcv45678912    2
00dfghjk14785236    3
                    4

[image]

I can't get my image to display...

**Note:**   POLICY.CONTRACT_ID is a concatenation of ('00', VARYING_REF, VARYING_ID) - e.g. 00abcdef12345678, where the VARYING_REF and VARYING_ID represent the parent policy of the related CONTRACTSTUB. Where that value is blank, there is no 'parent'. It is that (orphaned) VARYING_REF and VARYING_ID, that I want. (I will return '00'+VARYING_REF+VARYING_ID)

The combination 'dfghjk' and  '14785236' will return itself: 00dfghjk14785236

as will all the other combinations (return 00dfghjk14785236) found in CONTRACT_STUB.

I'm exhausted after that, Hope I haven't messed it up.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some sample data and desired results?  Yes, DB2 can perform recursive queries with CTEs, although there are some restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Clockwork-Muse. I'm not sure what you mean by sample data. I thought I was being very descriptive about inputs and outputs above. Input two VARCHARS: VARYING_ID and VARYING_REF. Output will be the parsed VARYING_ID (CONTRACTSTUB.STUB_ID) and VARYING_REF(CONTRACTSTUB.REF) from the last returned POLICY.CONTRACTSTUB_ID. I will look into CTEs though.

Comment: Sample data means please show us what some rows might contain, so that we can see what some actual data might look like.  It is generally a good idea to show enough rows in each input table to demonstrate various situations, and exceptions.  Then show what you want the output to look like, based on the input data you have shown us.  This helps people understand the problem, and helps us to verify whether a given answer is correct.

Comment: OK. Stand by.. I will get something. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Added some data now. I couldn't get my image to display, so I just put it inside <pre>.

Comment: ... And the example result rows that you want returned?

Comment: I've included that at the bottom. One row, one column. "The combination 'dfghjk' and '14785236' will return itself: 00dfghjk14785236

as will all the other combinations (return 00dfghjk14785236) found in CONTRACT_STUB. "

Answer (score 0):

I just read something about SQL recursion yesterday. There is a whole chapter about it in the [DB2 SQL Cookbook](http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html) (at least in version 9.5).